# Jmeter : How to increment a value inside the request

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a sample request like a bellow

```
{
  "schema": "urn:com.xyx9723.syodhnc:bulk.v1",
  "version": "7-06-26201",
  "msg": [
    {
      "topic": "tags/kdhud/${ID}/sadknnf",
      "ids": [
        {
          "_time": "2107-09-09 13:13:12",
          "id": "TID-2153656--00089312121"
        },
        {
          "_time": "2107-09-09 13:13:12",
          "id": "TID-2153656-00089312122"
        },
        {
          "_time": "2107-09-09 13:13:12",
          "id": "TID-2153656-00089312123"
        },
        {
          "_time": "2107-09-09 13:13:12",
          "id": "TID-2153656-00089312124"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When it comes to real test I have to send request with 100 IDS with increment values like (TID-2153656--00089312121, TID-2153656--00089312122, TID-2153656--00089312123 .... etc)

How to give incremental value in the request while sending a request in JMeter.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize somewhere variable id and then use it inside request several times, it will increase value with every occur:

```
${__intSum(${id},1,id)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Counter`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter). Starts wìth `00089312121`  Increment by `1` save in Reference Name `cnt` and Number Format `00000000`

Inside your request call it with prefix:

```
  TID-2153656-${cnt}
```