# Update the parameter value for each occurrence for the same request in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

I'm preparing data to be sent as part of HTTP request,
so the data preparation part is being done in BeanShell preprocessor.

As the request size changes, I need a variable length of JSON to be passed.
I am creating JSON body in for loop, but the parameters are not changing, Ex:

```
try{
    int[] po = {20, 30, 40, 50, 75};
    int rNum = getRandom(0,4);

    String name="${name}";
    String _class="${_class}";
    StringBuilder msgBody = new StringBuilder();
    msgBody.append("{\"name\":\"")
    .append(name)
    .append("\", \"class\":\"")
    .append(_class)
    .append("\", \"marks\":[");
    for (int i=0;i<po\"[rNum];i++)
    {   
        msgBody.append("{ \"subject\":\"${__P(marks${line_offset})}\"," },");
     }
     int length=msgBody.length()-1;
     log.info(String.valueOf(length));
    msgBody.setLength(length);
    msgBody.append("] }");
    vars.put("json",msgBody.toString());
}
```

`${__P(marks${line_offset})}` remains same inside the loop.

How to enable the change inside loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821446/jmeter-how-to-increment-a-value-inside-the-request/45822042#45822042

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In scrips use `props` instead function and `vars` instead of variable

```
  props.get("marks" + vars.get("line_offset"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect it to change? JMeter Properties are **global** for the whole JVM and shared across all threads. Therefore `${__P(marks${line_offset})}` will always have the same value unless you set it somewhere else. As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

> Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads

Few more things to check/fix:

1. In general your script will not work in its current state as it is full of errors, like:

   ```
   int[] po\" = {20, 30, 40, 50, 75}; // won't compile due to \"
   String class="${class}"; // won't compile as "class" is a reserved keyword
   etc.
   ```

   Next time you will face the problem please provide **exact** code
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting mainly because [Groovy performance is much better comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). Particular in your case you can have benefit from using [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) and/or [JsonOutput](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonOutput.html)
3. As per [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation - presumably the main cause of your problem:

   > JMeter processes function and variable references before passing the script field to the interpreter, **so the references will only be resolved once**. Variable and function references in script files will be passed verbatim to the interpreter, which is likely to cause a syntax error. In order to use runtime variables, please use the appropriate props methods, e.g.
   >
   > `props.get("START.HMS");`
   >
   > `props.put("PROP1","1234");`